# How to prove that Lie's theorem fails for a field of prime characteristic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Lie's theorem say that

> Let $L$ be a solvable, nonzero subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$, with $V$ a finite dimensional vector space over an algebraically closed field $F$ of characteristic zero. Then $V$ contains a common eigenvector for all the endomorphisms in $L$.

It is true for field with zero characteristic. I am unable to find a counter example when $\mathrm{char}~F= p$, a prime. Can anybody explain ?

Comment: How about a one dimensional Lie algebra spanned by an endomorphims $u$ that has no eigenvalues in $F$?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat, the question is about algebraically closed fields (otherwise the claim is false even in characteristic zero, by your same example)

Answer (score 3):

Take the $3$-dimensional lie algebra spanned by $1, x, d/dx$ acting on the vector space $k[x]/(x^p)$ in the obvious way. The point is that both $x$ and $d/dx$ are nilpotent with one dimensional kernels, but these kernels are different, so there can't possibly be a common eigenvector.

Whereas in characteristic 0, applying trace to the commutation relation $[d/dx,x]=1$, we get that 1 must act by zero on any finite dimensional representation and therefore the same relation tells us that any eigenvector of $x$ is a zero eigenvector of $d/dx$. So there is no hope of this sort of counter-example working in characteristic 0.

Comment: I don't understand why applying the trace tells you that the basis element $1\in L$ acts as $0$ in all finite dimensional representations. Are you saying that $1$ necessarily acts like a multiple of the identity? Why would that be so?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are matrices, then the trace of $[A,B]$ is zero.

Comment: 1 is central so it acts by a scalar on any irreducible representation.